# How two combine two xpath expressions into one?

Tags: xpath

Still fighting. Having these two xpath-expressions, both working, need to combine them into one:

```
(1) //scale[@gender="*" or @gender="m"][@age="*" or @age="39-59"]

(2) //d[@scid="hi"][@raw="10"]/@t
```

This is the XML (snippet):

```
<scales>
    <scale id="1" gender="*" age="*">
        <d scid="hi" raw="10" t="76" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="12" t="80" />
    </scale>
    <scale id="2" gender="m" age="*">
        <d scid="hi" raw="8" t="79" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="2" t="50" />
    </scale>
    <scale id="3" gender="*" age="19-39">
        <d scid="hi" raw="0" t="48" />
        <d scid="pn" raw="10" t="49" />
    </scale>
</scales>
```

Tried

```
//scale[@gender="*" or @gender="m"][@age="*" or @age="39-59"]/d[@scid="hi"][@raw="10"]@t
```

--> failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `/` before `@t` in your combined query, apart from that it looks fine and returns `t="76"` for given input.

```
//scale[@gender="*" or @gender="m"][@age="*" or @age="39-59"]/d[@scid="hi"][@raw="10"]/@t
```